# Is usergrid recommended for apps with real time functionality?

Tags: apigee, usergrid, mbaas, apigee-baas

Meaning, is it possible (and scalable) to build applications with chat functionality using only usergrid as backend? Or should I use some other solution for this specific functionality?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It probably wouldn't be advisable since UG doesn't implement any real-time protocols like websockets. If you used UG you would have to long poll for changes, which wouldn't make for a very good experience in something like a chat app.